# Setting an Angular service on an ES6 class property affects its functionality

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using ES6 with Angular following this guide http://angular-tips.com/blog/2015/06/using-angular-1-dot-x-with-es6-and-webpack/. It recommends defining services as classes. In a service definition I'm injecting the `$cookieStore` service and attaching it to the class:

```
export default class Authentication {
  constructor($cookieStore) {
    this.$cookieStore = $cookieStore;
  }

  setAuthenticatedAccount(account) {
    this.$cookieStore.put(JSON.stringify(account), 'authenticatedAccount');
  }
}
```

When `setAuthenticatedAccount` is called, `this.$cookieStore` executes but doesn't create the cookie `authenticatedAccount`. The cookie is created if you call `$cookieStore` without attaching it to `this`.

How can I define services as classes whilst avoiding this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the [`put`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore#put) function the wrong way. Try with this parameter order:

```
this.$cookieStore.put('authenticatedAccount', JSON.stringify(account));
```